# Find cells that are not in the header and are only in the first column of a table using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I used to have something like,

`$(elem).parents('li').find(...)`

Where elem was an item in a list, so it was easy to get a reference to all of the items in the list.  Now however I have added more information and decided to use a table, where the list fits into the table as follows.

[header][header][header]

[list 1][ cell ][ cell ]

[list 2][ cell ][ cell ]

[list 3][ cell ][ cell ]

I'm a little stuck creating the equivalent JQuery do a .find() on just the cells that have the list items in it.  The list items are always in the left-most table cells excluding the header.

Here is what the table looks like in html.

```
<table id="my-table">
<tr>
<th>Column 1</th>
<th>Column 2</th>
<th>Column 3</th>
<th>Column 4</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>list item 1</td>
<td>junk</td>
<td>junk</td>
<td>junk</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>list item 2</td>
<td>junk</td>
<td>junk</td>
<td>junk</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Are these in a table?  Perhaps posting a little of your HTML code will help.

Comment: are your headers in a thead tag?  your full HTML markup would be helpful to have.

Comment: added some html, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
$(elem).closest('tr').find(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the li's are always in the first cell of each row then this should work:

```
$('td:first-child>li')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you make use of `thead` and `tbody` you can find rows only in the body much easier.

Change your markup to something like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
       ... header rows ...
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       ... body rows ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then you can simply include `tbody` in your jquery selector to find just rows which are body rows.

Something like `#my-table tbody td:first-child`.  Where `first-child` will get you the first column.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you only the first column in each row.

```
var rows = $('tr :nth-child(1)', '#my-table').not('th');
```

If you want to loop through and do something to each of these now, just use:

```
rows.each(function()
{
   //Do something with the columnn
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution below will output the matching elements, first `<td>` in each row, to `<div id="#results"`

Working example at: http://jsfiddle.net/6faUf/

**HTML:**

```
<table border="5">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td><ul><li>List1</li></ul></td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
        <tr><td><ul><li>List2</li></ul></td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div id="results">The list values are: </div>
```

**JavaScript (jQuery):**

```
$('td:first-child').each(function(){
    var value = $(this).text();
    $("#results").append(value);
});
```

Comment: Not the answer I ended up going with, but thanks for the js fiddle example.  So many ways to do things in JQuery.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the cells that have the list items in them, you'd need the [:has()](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector, so there'd be something like that:

- `$(elem).closest('table').find('td:has(li) ...')` — if you need all the `li` in the table
- or `$(elem).closest('tr').find('td:has(li) ...')` — if you need all the `li` in the raw